# ftp transfer works with filezilla but not command line

Tags: bash, ftp

I am trying to transfer images to a server via ftp.

When I use Filezilla, it works: I can see my files on the server.

When I use these raw ftp commands:

```
ftp -p -v -n $server << EOF

    quote USER $user
    quote PASS $pass
    prompt off
    cd Stock
    mput *.jpg
    quit
EOF
```

it doesn't work, I can't see my images on the server, even if in my terminal it looks like it worked:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (89,151,93,136,207,15).
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
226 Transfer complete.
1225684 bytes sent in 1.88 secs (651.70 Kbytes/sec)
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I suspect the files are in a different directory than you expect.

Comment: You're putting the files into the user's home directory with ftp. Maybe in Filezilla you're putting them into a subdirectory. Add a `cd` command to go to the subdirectory.

Comment: @Barmar you're correct there's a directory I put the files into but I cd into that directory in my script too, I just forgot to include it in the script snippet

Comment: Are you sure the `cd` command is working? You didn't show the output from that in your transcript.

Comment: Other than that, I can't see a problem. It says it successfully uploaded the files, so they have to be somewhere.

Comment: `Opening ASCII mode`... aren't you missing a `binary` command?

Comment: @AlexP I know nothing about that! Can you elaborate? What would be the binary command?

Comment: Try using `ls` after putting the files (before `quit`) to confirm that they were written successfully.

Comment: @AlexP this is what ls is sending me back, no mention of a file, and why transfer complete? :  Entering Passive Mode (89,151,93,136,224,90).
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
226 Transfer complete.

Comment: Send `BIN` after `cd Stock` to transfer in binary mode because JPEGs are binary. In ASCII mode, it looks for CR/LF and translates them which is **bad** if they occur in the middle of an image!

Comment: @MarkSetchell ok that was the problem, adding BINARY before mput *.jpg solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add BINARY to force binary mode:

```
ftp -p -v -n $server << EOF
    quote USER $user
    quote PASS $pass
    prompt off
    cd Stock
    BINARY
    mput *.jpg
    quit
EOF
```